# Issues running logstash command as a subprocess from Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logstash

I'm trying to run a logstash command from rails console in the background to parse a log file to JSON and use the JSON to insert data into the DB using ActiveRecord. 
I'm facing issues with using either subprocess command or Spawn as all give me an error that Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find gem 'tzinfo-data java' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. Seems like Rails is unable to run the JVM code but I thought that logstash was written in Ruby only.

Command: `cat #{filePath} | #{logstashDir} -f #{logstash_config}`

Environment: 
Ruby v2.4.1p111
Rails v5.1.2
Logstash v5.5.0

Comment: Command using subprocess gem
    p1 = Subprocess.popen(["cat", filePath], {stdout: Subprocess::PIPE})
    p2 = Subprocess.popen([logstashDir, "-f", logstash_config, "-w", "8"], {stdin:p1.stdout, stdout:Subprocess::PIPE})
    p1.stdout.close()
    p2.communicate()

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. The way I made it work is to unset the subshell env variable "RUBYLIB" and "RUBYOPT". Put your command in sh like this:

```html
#!/usr/bin/env bash

unset RUBYLIB
unset RUBYOPT

#YOUR CODE
```